# How do I import Three.js OutlinePass jsm correctly?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm moving from using the plain Javascript Threejs to using the node version, and at the very start I'm already stuck.

**OrbitControls** was somehow fine, but when I import any postprocessing, I keep getting this error:

[image]

This is the code in question:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OutlinePass} from 'three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/OutlinePass';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import Stats from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/stats.module';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
camera.position.z = 2;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var outline = new OutlinePass(new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight), scene, camera);
```

As you can see I'm not doing anything with the OutlinePass yet since I couldn't get it to be imported. I've also tried importing EffectsComposer the same way and it also doesn't budge. The directory should be correct since it's suggested in intellisense.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use ES6 imports in that way if you directly open the website from a local server. Instead you need a build tool that bundles your app with its dependencies to a build file. This file can then be imported in `index.html`.

I suggest you use a start project like [three-jsm](https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm) that demonstrates a very basic build setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm using this as a quickstart to help make sure I do less things incorrectly.https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/Threejs-Boilerplate